# Pydantic Enum class validator

Tags: python, enums, pydantic

I have this enum class which checks for boolean values:

```
class MyEnumClass(int, Enum): 
    true = 1
    false = 0
```

I have 134 Pydantic Models (I am using Pydantic1); each of them has several fields validated through this enum class.

I realized that when I am going to do **MyPydanticModel.my_boolean_field** the result is not **1** or **0** but **MyEnumClass.true**  or **MyEnumClass.false**.

To face that, I was thinking to create in each pydantic Model this method:

```
@validator('first_boolean_field', 'second_boolean_field','....','last_boolean_field')
@classmethod
def get_boolean_value(cls, val):
    return val.value
```

It seems ridiculous to me to create 134 methods to do the same thing; is there a way to create a method in the enum class so that  PydanticModel.boolean_field returns the real value?

Comment: Why do these fields need to be `Enum`s? Why aren't they just `bool`s?

Comment: because what I am receiving are integers and the service that I am going to call is expecting integers;

Comment: @NicWorkAccount Python `bool`s are integers too: `issubclass(bool, int)  # True`. If you need a true integer you can always just call `int()`.

Comment: 0 and 1 are valid [booleans in pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/types/#booleans).

Comment: there are several reasons that oblige me to do as I did, so please do not answer with something different of what I asked, if I did like that is because I had to; is there a way of doing what I asked? yes? ok I am glad to hear; no? do not write anything else thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `use_enum_values` option. Take a look at the following example:

```py
from enum import Enum
from pydantic import BaseModel


class MyEnumClass(int, Enum): 
    true = 1
    false = 0


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    class Config:
        use_enum_values = True

    a: MyEnumClass
    b: MyEnumClass

m = MyModel(a=1, b=0)

print(m.a)
print(m.b)
```

Which prints `1` and `0`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad I could help! Please consider making this the accepted answer.